# Why do I get the wrong output message?

Tags: java

I keep getting a wrong output message, even though the program runs and gives me the correct answer.

```
public class SecondsOfTheYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        int daysInYear = 365;
        int hoursInDay = 12;
        int minutesInHour = 60;
        int secondsInMinute = 60;

        int secondsInYear = (daysInYear * hoursInDay * minutesInHour * secondsInMinute);

        System.out.println("There are " + secondsInYear + " seconds in a year");
    }    

}
```

Comment: Define "wrong output message" if it's giving you "the correct answer". The output message would appear to be the *only* feedback the code provides.

Comment: It was telling me that answer output was incorrect. That the number of seconds was wrong. This i realise was becuase i put twelve hours in a day - not 24! It would seem that i am indeed an imbecile!! Thanks for getting back so quick.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from there being 24 hours in a day, the program seems fine.

Can you be more specific about your problem? "I keep getting a wrong output message, even though the program runs and gives me the correct answer" is not very descriptive :S

Comment: Apologies for vague question. The number of seconds the program output was incorrect. I thought it was a syntax error, or some complicated coding error. It was actually because I put 12 hours in a day instead of 24. My brain had a temporary meltdown! Thanks for replying so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 24 hours in a day, you wrote there are 12.

Comment: Yes, Simone. To my horror and embarrasment, I have just realised what a fundamental, stupid error I made! Thanks for replying so quickly.